# Use of metaclass, setattr and property with Python and weird behavior

Tags: python, closures

I coded a `metaclass` that defines in run time properties of the class that use it. It just gets these attributes from the REQUIRED_KEYS attribute to then declare a `property`, for example:

```
class Base(object):
    REQUIRED_KEYS = ()

    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc):

            type.__init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc)
            for attr in cls.REQUIRED_KEYS:
                setattr(cls, attr, property(lambda self: self._dict.get(attr, None)))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._dict = dict(**kwargs)


class Config(Base):
    REQUIRED_KEYS = ('foo', 'bar')
```

If one key is not given the attribute defined in run time returns a `None` value. I would expected a right behaviour for the following execution, returning `1` and `None`:

```
config = Config(**{'foo': 1})
config.foo
config.bar
```

But it returns None for the `foo` attribute where the right value expected will be `1`.

If I modify the `lambda` used by the `property` function by one closure as the following snippet shows, it works fine.

```
class __metaclass__(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc):

        def get(attr):
            def _get(self):
                return self._dict.get(attr, None)
            return _get

        type.__init__(cls, name, bases, nmspc)
        for attr in cls.REQUIRED_KEYS:
            setattr(cls, attr, property(get(attr)))
```

Following the execution of the first snippet, I realised that the lambda function is always called with the last `attr` value. It means that when we are trying to access to the `foo` attribute the lambda uses the `bar` value.

does anybody know what is going on here ?

Answer (score 4):

This is how closures work in python.

The *value* of `attr` isn't stored in the lambda, only a reference to the *variable*.

In your code all lambdas contain the same reference to the `attr` variable, and when the lambda is called, it will contain its *last* value.

You can force a copy of the value by using a default argument:

```
setattr(cls, attr, property(lambda self, attr=attr: self._dict.get(attr, None)))
                                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realized about this issue with the references here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/), If a name is used within a code block, but it is not bound there (and is not declared global), the use is treated as a reference to the nearest enclosing function. (formatting mine). The name `attr` is not declared with in the lambda getter, so it is a **reference to** the variable `attr` in the metaclass `__init__` function, which always points to the last attribute. In addition, `dict(**kwargs)` (in the `Base` class init function) is not necessary because `kwargs` is already a dictionary (You can type `self._dict = kwargs`) and in your example, you cank initialize the class as `Config(foo=1)` instead of `Config(**{'foo':1})`

Comment: About the second coment, give a implicit sentence to build a dictionari from a kwars or a explicit is just different ways to do the same but not an issue. About the last comment, ```Config(**{'foo':'1'})``` in fact comes from something like ```d = {'foo': 1}; Config(**d)``` just relaxed in my comment to make it readable.